# How can I get more than 100 enrollments back for a user in Desire2Learn's Valence API?

Tags: desire2learn

The current method of getting the current user's enrollments, `/d2l/api/lp/{ver}/enrollments/myenrollments/`, renders only a limited number of enrollments (about 100). Is there a way short of calling the method again to get all the remaining enrollments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get current courses for a user in Desire2Learn's Valence API? What can we do to fetch when courses are in thousands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313486/how-do-i-get-current-courses-for-a-user-in-desire2learns-valence-api-what-can)

Answer (score 0):

The Valence API to retrieve the current user's list of enrollments pages the data in a *[paged result set](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/apicall.html#paged-result-sets)* data structure. The number of results sorted into each page is not controllable through the API. Accordingly, if you want to retrieve *all* a user's enrollments, you must make the call a number of times. On each call, check the top-level `HasMoreItems` boolean property in the returned paged result set structure -- it will tell you if there are more data pages to fetch.