# How do I get current courses for a user in Desire2Learn's Valence API? What can we do to fetch when courses are in thousands?

Tags: desire2learn

We need to find all the courses for a user whose `startDate` is less than today's date and `endDate` is greater than today's date. We are using API

```
/d2l/api/lp/{ver}/enrollments/myenrollments/?orgUnitTypeId=3
```

In one particular case I have more than 18 thousand courses against one user. The service can not return 18 thousand records at one go, I can only get 100 records at a time, so I need to use bookmark fields to fetch data in set of 100 records. Bookmark is the courseId of the last 100th record that we fetched, to get next set of 100 records.

```
/d2l/api/lp/{ver}/enrollments/myenrollments/?orgUnitTypeId=3&bookmark=12528
```

I need to repeat the loop 180 times, which results in `"Request time out" error`. 
I need to filter the record on the basis of `startDate` and `endDate`, no sorting criteria is mentioned which can sort the data on the basis of `startDate` or `endDate`. Can anyone help me to find out the way to sort these data, or tell any other API which can do such type of sorting?

Note: All the 18 thousand records has property `"IsActive":true`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting to the list of org units by user, you can try getting to the user by the list of org units. You could try using `/d2l/api/lp/{ver}/orgstructure/{orgUnitId}/descendants/?ouTypeId={courseOfferingType}` to retrieve the entire list of course offering IDs descended from the highest common ancestor known for the user's enrollments. You can then loop through `/d2l/api/lp/{ver}/courses/{orgUnitId}` to fetch back the course offering info for each one of those org units to pre-filter and cut out all the course offerings you don't care about based on dates. Then, for the ones left, you can check for the user's enrollment in each one of those to figure out which of your smaller set the user matches with.

This will certainly result in *more* calls to the service, not less, so it only has two advantages I can see:

- You *should* be able to get the entire starting set of course offerings you need off the hop rather than getting it back in pages (although it's entirely possible that this call will get turned into a paging call in the future and the "fetch all the org units at once" nature it currently has deprecated).
- If you need to do this entire use-case for more than one user, you can fetch the org structure data *once*, cache it, and then only do queries for users on the subset of the data.

In the mean time, I think it's totally reasonable to request an enhancement on the enrollments calls to provide better filtering (active/nonactive, start-dates, end-dates, and etc): I suspect that such a request might see more traction than a request to give control to clients over paging (i.e. number of responses in each page frame).